# FileMaker Script to Hide Object

Tags: filemaker

I want to ask. If i have 2 Field in FileMakerPro 15. Accesories and Accesories Type. Accesories is a Field Using Checkbox. the valuelist in the checkbox is Mouse Printer And Scanner. What script must i input to make Accersories Type Field from hidden to show up when Printer or Scanner Record being checked in the checkbox?

Sry for my bad english and bad explanation anyway and Thx before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No script needed, assuming you are using a relatively new version of FileMaker.

Set up a hide condition on your Accesories Type field, so that it will be hidden when Accesories is either Printer or Scanner, like this.

`FilterValues(Accesories;"Printer¶Scanner") ≠ ""`